# Remove all characters after the 2nd occurrence of "-" in each element of a vector

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I would like to remove all characters after the 2nd occurrence of "-" in each element of a vector.

```
 Initial string  
 aa-bbb-cccc    =>    aa-bbb
 aa-vvv-vv      =>    aa-vvv
 aa-ddd         =>    aa-ddd
```

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Judging by the sample input and expected output, I assume you need to remove all beginning with the 2nd hyphen.

You may use

```
sub("^([^-]*-[^-]*).*", "\\1", x)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qOZMSZ/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^-]*-[^-]*)`  - Group 1 capturing 0+ chars other than `-`, `-` and 0+ chars other than `-`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars (in a TRE regex like this, a dot matches line break chars, too.)

The `\\1` (`\1`) is a backreference to the text captured into Group 1.

[R demo](http://ideone.com/MPfE0T):

```
x <- c("aa-bbb-cccc", "aa-vvv-vv", "aa-ddd")
sub("^([^-]*-[^-]*).*", "\\1", x)
## => [1] "aa-bbb" "aa-vvv" "aa-ddd"
```