# Remove characters including and after third hyphen

Tags: r, string

I have a dataframe `df` and want to remove everything including and after the third '`-`' in the column '`case_id`':

`df`

```
case_id             unit

TCGA-3A-01-03-9441  27  
TCGA-9C-01-04-9641  15
TCGA-1E-01-05-9471  6
```

This is the desired output:

`df`

```
case_id     unit

TCGA-3A-01  27  
TCGA-9C-01  15
TCGA-1E-01  6
```

Comment: No because that is actually for second occurrence and it is not in context of a df

Comment: Ah right yeah, the title was misleading. My bad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all characters after the 2nd occurrence of "-" in each element of a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622326/remove-all-characters-after-the-2nd-occurrence-of-in-each-element-of-a-vecto)

Comment: This is the same question. You just have to add another `*-[^-]` to the regex pattern since you want to take 3 hyphens, not 2. And to apply a function to each row of a dataframe, you can just use `mutate` or an apply function. To repeat that question, the full command would be the following: `mutate(df, case_id = gsub("^([^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*).*", "\\1", case_id))`

Comment: if it is a fixed format you can also use `substr(df$case_id,1,10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(case_id = str_replace(case_id, "^(([^-]+-){2}[^-]+)-.*", "\\1"))
```

-output

```
      case_id unit
1 TCGA-3A-01   27
2 TCGA-9C-01   15
3 TCGA-1E-01    6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(case_id = c("TCGA-3A-01-03-9441", "TCGA-9C-01-04-9641", 
"TCGA-1E-01-05-9471"), unit = c(27L, 15L, 6L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```